# 'Do/While' or 'If' for nested like coordinate systems?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to learn game making in Unity2D and I need a help about coordination system. As you see there are 2 panels on top of each other. SpawnArea panel is green one and TowerArea panel is pink one. Yellow square is imaginary borders, not in the game. I want enemies to be summoned to be inside the green area but not inside the yellow area. So this will be a tower defense game. There will be a tower in the middle and enemies will appear around it and attack the tower in the middle. What I want is for them not to be summoned too close or too far away. And btw enemies will only be visible when they are inside the pink area. (As you see there are 3 enemies gameObject in the Hierarchy one is red squire which is visible and other two not visible because of they are in the green area, not in pink area)

[image: mainScene]

I created system mostly and it is working well right now. I got help from chatgpt and copilot and this was what they suggested to me. If I understand correct with this code it will check random number everytime and if it is smaller than 250 it will reroll. I wonder is there a simpler way to do this? It seemed a bit unnecessary to roll the dice over 700 and roll the dice again every time the score was lower than 250. Instead, wouldn't it be a better solution to determine all the coordinates and then roll the dice?

```
    void SpawnEnemy()
    {
        float randomX, randomY;

        do
        {
            randomX = Random.Range(-700, 700);
            randomY = Random.Range(-670, 670);
        } while ((Mathf.Abs(randomX) <= 250 && Mathf.Abs(randomY) <= 250));

        Vector3 spawnPosition = new Vector3(randomX, randomY, 0);
        GameObject enemy = Instantiate(enemyPrefab, spawnPosition, Quaternion.identity);

        enemy.transform.SetParent(towerArea.transform, false);
    }
```

I mean something like this more useful or first one is better?

```
    void SpawnEnemy()
    {
        float randomX, randomY;

        if (Random.Range(1, 3) == 1)
        {
            randomX = Random.Range(-700, -250);
        }
        else
        {
            randomX = Random.Range(250, 700);
        }

        if (Random.Range(1, 3) == 1)
        {
            randomY = Random.Range(-670, -250);
        }
        else
        {
            randomY = Random.Range(250, 670);
        }

        Vector3 spawnPosition = new Vector3(randomX, randomY, 0);
        GameObject enemy = Instantiate(enemyPrefab, spawnPosition, Quaternion.identity);

        enemy.transform.SetParent(towerArea.transform, false);
    }
```

Comment: your first while loop makes zero sense, why would you creeate a number between -700 and 700 only if you want -250 -> 250 if thats what you wanted?  just create a random number between those points for x and y, once, no need for a loop.. which is wasting time cycles and likely on the main thread so will cause your game to halt while it does it.    The second uses a different area, so is arguably not really a comparible. but it would perform better but achieves different things

Comment: So the actual range that is random is +/- (250 to 750)? Then adjust the calculation to the needs: `var rngPosition = rng.Next(250, 750) * (rng.Next(0,1) * 2 - 1)` (tweak the ranges if necessary). The second random procuces `1` or `-1` which result then in positive/negative coordinates with the multiplication.

Comment: i forgot the c# random excludes the upper boundary -> `rngPosition = rng.Next(250, 751) * (rng.Next(0,2) * 2 - 1)`

Comment: @LittleBit that's actually what I'm looking for. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: shall i post it as official answer?

Answer (score 1):

To answers your question. "I mean something like this more useful or first one is better?"

Yes the second code block is less CPU intensive.

```
void SpawnEnemy()
{
    float randomX, randomY;

    if (Random.Range(1, 3) == 1)
    {
        randomX = Random.Range(-700, -250);
    }
    else
    {
        randomX = Random.Range(250, 700);
    }

    if (Random.Range(1, 3) == 1)
    {
        randomY = Random.Range(-670, -250);
    }
    else
    {
        randomY = Random.Range(250, 670);
    }

    Vector3 spawnPosition = new Vector3(randomX, randomY, 0);
    GameObject enemy = Instantiate(enemyPrefab, spawnPosition, Quaternion.identity);

    enemy.transform.SetParent(towerArea.transform, false);
}
```

The first code block you showed

```
void SpawnEnemy()
{
    float randomX, randomY;

    do
    {
        randomX = Random.Range(-700, 700);
        randomY = Random.Range(-670, 670);
    } while ((Mathf.Abs(randomX) <= 250 && Mathf.Abs(randomY) <= 250));

    Vector3 spawnPosition = new Vector3(randomX, randomY, 0);
    GameObject enemy = Instantiate(enemyPrefab, spawnPosition, Quaternion.identity);

    enemy.transform.SetParent(towerArea.transform, false);
}
```

does a DO WHILE loop, if the number is always not in the range that you have defined it will keep on running the code which can get very CPU intensive, and might create a stock overflow if you get unlucky enough.

TL;DR use the seconds code block.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you for you suggestions on this. I will add then right now.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a different approach, I'd use polar coordinates. Distance and direction/angle.

*(I have no experience with Unity, but it should look something like this)*

```
float angle = Random.Range(0, Math.PI * 2);
float distance = Random.Range(250, 700);

float randomX = Math.Cos(angle) * distance;
float randomY = Math.Sin(angle) * distance;
```

But this also means that the yellow and green rect become circles.

With your current solution the enemies spawn closer on the vertical and horizontal axis and further away on the diagonals. Like `700, 670` is over `950`units away, way further than both `700, 0` and `0, 670`. This also means that enemies that spawn diagonally will be easier to kill since you have more time; to notice, to act and maybe even to kill. The game is biased.